# Outlook client receive email from sendgrid have no download option for the picture

Tags: html, image, outlook, sendgrid

Our company outlook client receive email from sendgrid email system. However, the picture in email have no option of download the picture. How can I fix the issue?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, can you please add a screenshot of this download button? Also is this button showing up in other email clients?